# Running for loop with user input

Tags: windows, batch-file, putty, input-type-file

I wish to create a batch file which would take user input of, a set of IP's.
All these IP's would have to automatically open **individual putty session** and execute commands.

**start C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\putty.exe -ssh userID@HostIP -pw password -m command.txt**

this is the command I am using.
At the moment I am using the same command "n" no of times in a batch file depending upon the number of HostIP I have.

Now I wish to get a prompt to enter a set of IP's in one shot, and these induvidual IP's should get substituted in the HostIP part of the command.

Once i enter the a set of IP's as user input.. it should count them, and create the above script for individual HostIPs for execution.

is that possible. kindly help with the full batch script :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to key in the list, or read the list from a file? What format would this input take?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because we are not here to write your code for you.